# HTML5 - Validation messages

Tags: forms, html, validation, semantics

What element should I use to show validation messages (errors) to the user? Which one is more semantic in HTML5?

Answer (score 3):

You could consider adding an ARIA role of 'alert' or 'status'. I don't think that semantically any of the HTML elements is any better than `<div class="error">`

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to show a javascript error box containing the erro(s).

**EDIT:** For server side validation we use a `<div>` that gets filled after an ajax call.

Comment: Ok, but i always do client-side and server-side validation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I typically would use a `div` with an `error` or `notice` class to show errors.